# UdpClient beginreceive how to detect when server is off

Tags: c#, sockets, udpclient

I have an application that is reading data from a Udp server on 32 different ports that I need to process. I'm using the UdpClient.BeginReceive that is calling itself because I want to listen all the time :

```
 private void ProcessEndpointData(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        UdpClient client = result.AsyncState as UdpClient;

        // points towards whoever had sent the message:
        IPEndPoint source = new IPEndPoint(0, 0);

        // schedule the next receive operation once reading is done:
        client.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(this.ProcessEndpointData), client);

        // get the actual message and fill out the source:
        this.DecodeDatagram(new DatagrammeAscb()
        {
            Datagramme = this.ByteArrayToStructure<Datagram>(client.EndReceive(result, ref source)) 
        });
    }
```

When I stop the server side, the function is waiting for data (that is normal behavior). What I would like to do is to detect when the server is disconnected and then close all my clients.

I'm asking myself if I should use sockets class to have more controls or just maybe I'm missing something here.

Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: the whole point of UDP is it doesnt care if there is something the other end ..

Comment: You could send a poison packet. UDP itself won't give you this. Btw, TCP neither.

Comment: Personnally, I'd do it on several levels: 1. Send Poison packets ( Inform Clients, Server is going down ). Send not only one but several (UDP is unreliable). 2. Have some sort of timeout and "are you there"-functionality. So if there is no com with the server for x amount of time, then send some sort of ping and if there is no answer in reasonable time, assume server is down.

Comment: The problem is that I don't handle server side (code) and I can't change anything. If possible I would like to handle the timeout without a while, because I'm trying to make something efficient especially with CPU. Thanks for the hints.